# GTX 1080 Ti: Unable to load X Server Display Configuration page

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I can connect DVI LCD with GTX1080Ti when I try to replace with VGA LCD by using VGA-HDMI converter. The screen gives a message `No input signal` but in the display setting LCD gets detected. The Nvidia X Server setting can also detect the screen. But, in the X Server Display Configuration, there is a message:

> Unable to load X Server Display Configuration page

as shown below.

[image: NVIDIA X Server settings]

Now, the DVI LCD is connected through its VGA port using the HDMI converter.